# Shifting the plot domain

Tags: plotting

I integrated this system of two differential equations

```
b = 0.2001;
k = 8 Pi;
G = 1.5;
Z = 1.1065;
U = 0.478;

s = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][R][t] == (R[t] Sqrt[k \[Rho][t]])/
    Sqrt[3], 
   Derivative[1][\[Rho]][
     t] == -((3 G \[Rho][t] Derivative[1][R][t])/R[t]) + 
     18 Derivative[1][R][t]^2 Z \[Rho][t]^(b + 
       1) (G R[t])/U + 
     3 Derivative[1][R][t] Z \[Rho][
       t]^b(G R[t]^2)/U Derivative[1][\[Rho]][t], 
   R[1000] == 100000, \[Rho][1000] == .000001}, {R, \[Rho]}, {t, 0 , 
   1000}]
```

Mathematica finds a singular point when the time t=884.8375974007517. I plotted the solutions starting from this time and I fitted them with a power-law function.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[{R[t]} /. s], 
   25000*(t - 884.8375974007517)^((2 b + 1)/3)}, {t, 
   884.8375974007517, 890}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["t", Medium], Style["R(t)", Medium]}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]

Plot[{Evaluate[{\[Rho][t]} /. 
         s], ((2 b + 1)^2/(3 K)) (t - 
           884.8375974007517)^(-2)}, {t, 884.86, 890}, PlotRange -> All, 
      Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {Style["t", Medium], Style["\[Rho](t)", Medium]}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
```

This is what I get

[image]
[image]

I would like to make the x-axis starting from t=0 instead of t=884.8375974007517. I think is something related to the plot rather than the integration.

Comment: `Plot[{Evaluate[{R[t]} /. s], 25000*(t)^((2 b + 1)/3)}, {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["t", Medium], Style["R(t)", Medium]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "shift all the x-axis to zero"?  Also, please provide `s`, so that your code can be run by readers.

Answer (score 2):

You are after `FrameTicks`:

```
min = Min@First[s][[1, 2]]["Domain"]
```

> 884.838

```
trans = Table[{min + i, i}, {i, 0, 10}]
```

> {{884.838, 0}, {885.838, 1}, {886.838, 2}, {887.838, 3}, {888.838, 
>     4}, {889.838, 5}, {890.838, 6}, {891.838, 7}, {892.838, 
>     8}, {893.838, 9}, {894.838, 10}}

```
ticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {trans, Automatic}};

Plot[{Evaluate[{R[t]} /. s], 25000*(t - min)^((2 b + 1)/3)}, {t, min, 
  890}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["t-" <> ToString[min], Medium], 
   Style["R(t)", Medium]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, FrameTicks -> ticks]

Plot[{Evaluate[{ρ[t]} /. 
    s], ((2 b + 1)^2/(3 k)) (t - min)^(-2)}, {t, min + 0.02, 890}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["t-" <> ToString[min], Medium], 
   Style["ρ(t)", Medium]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not according to the label "t". The x-axis should be labeled "$t-884.838$" instead, shouldn't it?